# Homestead.yaml does not exist after homestead installation

Tags: homestead

I installed homestead box by the documentation from here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.5.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    box:
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.5.0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

I am having windows 7 and cygwin.

Now I try to edit the file:

~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml

```
ls ~/.homestead
ls: cannot access /home/Darius/.homestead: No such file or directory
```

So not even directory exists. Is the documentation wrong? Where is this file?

**Update**

I run search in my computer and it did not find such file. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

run:

```
homestead init
```

that should create the file homestead.yaml

Comment: I get: in cygwin "-bash: homestead: command not found". In cmd: "'homestead' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."